AWS Elastic Beanstalk Intance Getting Nuked With Get Requests
My Eb is getting nuked by some kind of FUZZER trying to find creds.
 11 02:31:02 ip-10-0-2-187 web[114840]: 2024-05-11 02:31:02,197: [ERROR] Unauthorized access: ip:185.142.236.43, 10.0.6.162
May 11 02:31:02 ip-10-0-2-187 web[114840]: user_agent:Unknown
May 11 02:31:02 ip-10-0-2-187 web[114840]: Path:robots.txt
May 11 02:31:02 ip-10-0-2-187 web[114840]: AmazonTraceID:Root=1-663ed866-357a71ce6d3ea24920b0a048
May 11 02:31:02 ip-10-0-2-187 web[114840]: INFO:     10.0.6.162:0 - "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 418 I'm a Teapot
May 11 02:31:03 ip-10-0-2-187 web[114840]: 2024-05-11 02:31:03,324: [ERROR] Unauthorized access: ip:185.142.236.43, 10.0.6.162
May 11 02:31:03 ip-10-0-2-187 web[114840]: user_agent:Unknown

May 11 02:31:03 ip-10-0-2-187 web[114840]: Path:sitemap.xml
May 11 02:31:03 ip-10-0-2-187 web[114840]: AmazonTraceID:Root=1-663ed867-4543903002ca711c5bcdb368
May 11 02:31:03 ip-10-0-2-187 web[114840]: INFO:     10.0.6.162:0 - "GET /sitemap.xml HTTP/1.1" 418 I'm a Teapot
May 11 02:31:04 ip-10-0-2-187 web[114840]: 2024-05-11 02:31:04,824: [ERROR] Unauthorized access: ip:185.142.236.43, 10.0.6.162
May 11 02:31:04 ip-10-0-2-187 web[114840]: user_agent:Unknown
May 11 02:31:04 ip-10-0-2-187 web[114840]: Path:.well-known/security.txt
May 11 02:31:04 ip-10-0-2-187 web[114840]: AmazonTraceID:Root=1-663ed868-79e461bc23f5ab1d48765055
May 11 02:31:04 ip-10-0-2-187 web[114840]: INFO:     10.0.6.162:0 - "GET /.well-known/security.txt HTTP/1.1" 418 I'm a Teapot
May 11 02:31:06 ip-10-0-2-187 web[114840]: 2024-05-11 02:31:06,323: [ERROR] Unauthorized access: ip:185.142.236.43, 10.0.6.162
May 11 02:31:06 ip-10-0-2-187 web[114840]: user_agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36

The Ips Are not mine , its the IP from the attacker.
Sometimes I get millions per minute , I need to have port 443 open to any IP because of the nature of the service that Im hosting , and I cannot blacklist thousends of IP addreses.
Any suggestions?
Maybe installing a WAF?
My server is really getting nuked and they managed to take it down for a minute or two.

I'm returning a 418 on purpose.
